# React native image "Unable to resolve module"

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I'm trying to add a logo to my app, and I require the image from a folder inside the project's folder. I followed the docs, and it won't recognize my logo image, I even tried with a different folder and still nothing.
"The module './logowo.png' could not be found"
[image]

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As by your error, **"The module './logowo.png' could not be found"**. You might have mis spelled the name of your image instead of **./logwo.png**. The path you have mentioned is fine. It works perfectly for me, when i try to mimic the error. You may use it like below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Logo extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('./logwo.png')} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try importing the image first?

For example:

At line 9:

```
import imagename from './logwo.png'
```

and the image tag:

```
<Image source = { imagename } />
```